# Quantum entanglement of spin along multiple orthogonal axes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement

Picture an entangled pair of spin 1/2-spin particles with total spin 0. In the diagram, particle 1 of the pair is moving to the left (-y), and particle 2 to the right (+y).

If a z-oriented SG$^*$ is used to detect the spin direction of particle 1 on the left, then the spin direction of particle 2 can be predicted with 100% certainty by using another z-oriented SG on the right. For example, if the left SG finds particle 1 to have spin $\frac{\hbar}{2}$, there is be a 100% probability that a z-directed SG on the right will detect particle 2 as having spin $-\frac{\hbar}{2}$.

Now consider leaving the left SG unchanged (pointing to +z), and rotating the right SG so it will point to +x. If particle 1 is detected on the left to have spin $\frac{\hbar}{2}$, two possibilities can be considered for what will happen when particle 2 reaches the +x-directed SG:

- Particle 2 is detected with 100% probability as having spin $-\frac{\hbar}{2}$ in the +x-direction, or
- Particle 2 is detected with a 50% probability of having spin $-\frac{\hbar}{2}$ in the +x direction, and 50% of having spin $+\frac{\hbar}{2}$ in the -x direction.

In the second case, obviously, it may turn out that the total spin of the system is not equal to zero.

<sup>*SG: Stern-Gerlach apparatus</sup>
[image: Two Stern-Gerlach apparatuses directed along z-direction]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited to add :** *This is an answer to a different question. The real answer is in the comments*

If both particle are measures along the same direction, the obtained results would be opposite whatever the direction is. The 0 totalt spin of the singlet state means that there is no specific direction associated to it.

More formally for the $x$ direction, the EPR (singlet) state is
$$\begin{align}
\left|\Psi^-\right>=\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right>-\left|\downarrow\uparrow\right>\right)
\end{align}$$
To rewrite it in the $x$ basis, one use
$$\begin{align}
\left|\rightarrow\right>&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\left|\uparrow\right>+\left|\downarrow\right>\right)&
\left|\leftarrow\right>&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\left|\uparrow\right>-\left|\downarrow\right>\right)
\\
\left|\uparrow\right>&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\left|\leftarrow\right>+\left|\rightarrow\right>\right)&
\left|\downarrow\right>&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\left|\leftarrow\right>-\left|\rightarrow\right>\right)
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right>&=\frac12\left(\left|\leftarrow\leftarrow\right>-\left|\leftarrow\rightarrow\right>+\left|\rightarrow\leftarrow\right>+\left|\rightarrow\rightarrow\right>\right)
\\
\left|\downarrow\uparrow\right>&=\frac12\left(\left|\leftarrow\leftarrow\right>+\left|\leftarrow\rightarrow\right>-\left|\leftarrow\rightarrow\right>+\left|\rightarrow\rightarrow\right>\right)&
\end{align}$$
Therefore 
$$
\left|\Psi^-\right>=\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right>-\left|\downarrow\uparrow\right>\right)
=\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\left|\rightarrow\leftarrow\right>-\left|\leftarrow\rightarrow\right>\right),
$$
which is the result you predicted from the null total spin.

Comment: Frédéric, I like your answer, but my own reading of his question was a bit different. Here's a different version of the same problem, stated perhaps a bit more bluntly: If you detect an entangled net-zero-spin 1/2 spin particle pair using SGs at right angles to each other, spin conservation appears to be violated _no matter what results you get_, simply because there is no way to add up the orthogonal spin axis results to get zero total angular momentum. That's why I lean towards saying it stays quantum -- there is still entanglement in the system -- even after both detections have been made.

Comment: @Frédéric Grosshans Your calculations show that the singlet state is directionally independent, there is no doubt. Assume that SG{+z} measurement of the 1st particle spin direction finds it in +z axis directed spin. What is the result of measurement, we should expect from SG{+x}?

Comment: OK, I didn't read the question properly. If the first measurement is $+\hbar/2$ alon $z$, the second spin is in state $\left|\downarrow\right>$. Measuring this second spin in the $x$ direction would give a random result. This measurement does *not* allow to measure the total spin of the system, hence the apparent spin non-conservation.

Comment: @ Frédéric Grosshan It is strange to me, that spin does not conservate. What does it happen for total system, which consist of SG{+z}+entangled pair+SG{+x}? Does it mean the total system spin will not concerve?

Comment: 1st: you don't need to prepare an entangled pair to have this effect. It appears also if you have a single spin polarized along z and measured along x. 2nd: I don't think the spin is conserved in this case. If it were conserved, it would be possible to measure simultaneously the spin both along x and along z. The non-conservating operation is the "wave-packet" reduction (in Copenhagen interpretation), which transforms $|\uparrow\rangle=\frac1{\sqrt2}(|\rightarrow\rangle+|\leftarrow\rangle)$ into a mixture of $|\rightarrow\rangle$ and $|\leftarrow\rangle$. But if the observer is included ...

Comment: ... in the description, there is no wave-packet reduction and the spin is conserved.

Comment: Not reducing the wave function is a good way to avoid the problem. From John Bell's writings on quantum-classical boundaries, I suspect that is how he would have approached it. Not reducing the wave function and entangling classical objects are both ways of saying that tiny residual quantum linkages persist even in nominally classical systems. If you think of locality in classical physics as an asymptotic limit approached by driving entanglement towards zero, that's perhaps not even that surprising.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question.

A quick answer is that spin entanglement can involve large-scale objects also. When a particle spin is detected by the Stern-Gerlach apparatus, the *entire apparatus* becomes entangled with the other (still isolated) particle. This allows a seemingly sold answer for the particle spin that contradicts conservation, but the answer is an illusion in the sense that spin state of the apparatus as a whole will now be "ready" to balance out whatever result the other particle gives.

Comment: tnks for clarifing my question.

Comment: Sergio, it was a good question and you are most welcome. And to address your original question more directly: Your second option of 50/50 is definitely what an SG will do experimentally (see Feynman Lectures, Vol III). Also, _all_ possible readings will nominally violate conservation of angular momentum, not just some, as Frédéric also noted above. A quick graphical way to verify that something is amiss is to draw the four possible outcomes of the SGs and try to add them like classical angular momentum vectors. It doesn't work. The resulting vectors are non-zero and also have invalid lengths.

Comment: The claim that a measurement apparatus becomes entangled **after the measurement** is a piece dangerous philosophy, if not to say “heresy”. Let’s remind that in the standard theory a measurement on a 2-state system, contrary, *destroys* its entanglement with anything else, so “the other (still isolated) particle” will not be entangled anymore. Note that Ī don’t consider *non-selective* measurements and mixed states.

Comment: Suggestion: Shrink your measurement system, including the observer, down to the size of a small molecule. Run the numbers, and see if it's still heresy to say that new entanglement relationships emerge after a detection. If you _don't_ see any emerge, watch out: Somewhere in your setup you inadvertently violated one of the universe's global conservation laws.